# How to know which action was called on store.$subscribe in Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, pinia

This is my store

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useUserStore = defineStore({
    id: "userStore",
    state: () => ({
        userInfo: "",
        userFeatures: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        setUserInfo(userInfo){
            this.userInfo = userInfo;
        },
        setUserFeatures(userFeatures){
            this.userFeatures = userFeatures;
        }
    }
  });
```

I am subscribing to the *userSore* to listen for changes. Now my question is how can I differentiate between *setUserInfo()* and *setUserFeatures()* call?

I am looking for something similar to Vuex where we check for *mutation.type*.

Comment: Don't the Vue devtools provide that too?

Comment: @kissu I have logic to run based on which action triggers the state change. Dev tools are not going to work.

Comment: [is this what you're after?](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html#subscribing-to-actions)